# Can't change size of Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

I have custom `UIView` which I made in `Xib` file, there is `UICollectionView` inside of it and I can't change the cell size of this collection view. It's fixed at 50x50 and I can't modify it via storyboard. I also tried using the FlowDelegateLayout and returning my desired cellSize in the ViewController but the size still stays at 50x50

Why is that and how can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: What are the constraints that you have set?

Comment: Collection View has fixed height of 28 and vertical spacing: 2 from label and leading and trailing to label